# Adding dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I need to add/join three dictionaries with common keys and different values i need to join all the three dictionaries as a single dictionary where they should be joined together. I have :

```
 Dict1 = {"a" : 10 ,"b" : "vignesh", "C" : "bangalore"} 

 Dict2 = {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"} 

 Dict3 = {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"}
```

i need the output as :

```
Dict4  =  { "i1" : {"a" : 10 ,"b" : "vignesh", "C" : "bangalore"},"i2" : {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"} , "i3" : {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"} }
```

Comment: `Dict4 = dict(i1=Dict1,i2=Dict2,i3=Dict3)`

Comment: Thats great! good luck with that, if you get stuck, ask a question with what you've tried and researched. Read [ask] for more guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dict4 = {}
for i, d in zip(range(1, len(listOfDicts) + 1), listOfDicts):
    Dict4[f'i{i}'] = d
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . I am also attach the screenshot of the output .

```
Dict1 = {"a" : 10 ,"b" : "vignesh", "C" : "bangalore"} 
Dict2 = {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"} 
Dict3 = {"a" : 25 ,"b" : "logesh", "C" : "mumbai"} 
Dict4 = { }
Dict4["i1"]=Dict1;
Dict4["i2"]=Dict2;
Dict4["i3"]=Dict3;
print(Dict4)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This will get you what you need:

`dict(i1=Dict1,i2=Dict2,i3=Dict3)`